# avoiding container strings in dependency injection in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

New to symfony and php. I was able to successfully define a service and inject the doctrine entity manager into it. It works fine but during the initialization I have to pass a string that contains the service name as follows:

```
    $eRep = $this->container->get('employee_repository');
```

Can this be avoided? Can this be converted to something more elegant like

```
   $eRep = $this->container->getEmployeeRepository();
```

The service is defined as:

```
services:
employee_repository:
    class: AppBundle\Repository\EmployeeRepository
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Apologies for the noob question.
**EDIT**

Can I get access to a service container inside another class say EmployeeEnvelope and call as follows:

```
class EmployeeEnvelope{

    public function getEmployeeRepository()
    {               
        return $this->container->get('employee_repository');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're requesting the service from a controller, you can setup your controller to be a service too. Then you can pass the employee repository service to it using dependency injection.

That way you will not have the string reference in the controller, but in the configuration.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: Can I get access to the container in a generic PHP class? Please check my edits

Comment: There is no generic way to do it. It's not a good practice. If your class implements business logic you may consider making it a service and using dependency injection to provide it with other services it needs. Otherwise you may pass the empoyee entities it needs to that class in a constructor or with a set method.